# Revert a older version of a gitbook

Tags: git, gitbook

How do you revert to an older merge of a gitbook version. I had accidentally merged a wrong and I need to change it back urgently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rollback your merged change
[Read this](https://docs.gitbook.com/collaboration/activity#rolling-back-to-a-previous-version)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Docs has pretty useless documentation for this process, despite it seeming to be a regular issue.

First, you must be an **Administrator** in your GitBook workspace to have access to the Rollback function.

When you open your GitBook, you will see the *History* tab in the upper right. Go to this tab, then select *Change History*, then *Space* to view all of the merged change requests that have occurred in your GitBook workspace.

Scroll to the merged change request that you want to restore your GitBook's state to, and click the **three dots** to the right of the change request name. You will then be presented with the **Rollback** function.

!  DO NOT just click the change request, this will send you out into your main workspace to view the old change request. This is actually a pretty good way to verify that this is in fact the one you wanted before rolling back the workspace.